# What button do I press to make a waypoint on my mini map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One day, in Minecraft, I wanted to explore a cave. However I got lost on the way and cant find my way back. I really wanted a waypoint at my home, what button do I press?
I also have the waypoint mod and reis minimap installed

Comment: If you do not have a mod installed, you can not create a waypoint in minecraft.

Comment: Which waypoint mod? rei's minimap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On rei's minimap the button M should work for using it's full features. There should also be an in-game key config so that you can customize which button to whatever function. You must also specify WHICH waypoint mod as there are many

Comment: @MinecraftGamer If this answer helped please be sure to mark it as an answer. It helps other users as well!